# missing libary in vitis-tool-gpu docker container

Tags: xilinx

I've used the Vitis docker tool container using only the CPU and Conda worked fine; however, when I want to use the GPU version for docker, I get the below error. I tried building the environment twice and each time it has failed to import the right libraries.

```
(vitis-ai-caffe) sam@Itec:~/cf_resnet50$ vai_q_caffe quantize -model float/trainval.prototxt -weights float/trainval.caffemodel
vai_q_caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director
```

How might I resolve this error? I will be happy to receive any help.

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.0.0 there is an issue in the docker with the protobuf library version.  It can be resolved by patching the conda_requirements.txt.  To do so, open the conda_requirements.txt in a text editor and add the following two lines, then build the GPU docker:

```
libprotobuf==3.10.1
protobuf==3.10.1
```